# Which app delegate function to send notifications in background?

Tags: swift, firebase, background, notifications, appdelegate

I have searched this topic for a while but not found anything that does exactly what I want. I have this code that checks for when a new post is added to the database, and when that happens, I want to send the user a notification. Here is that code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("\(mySchool!)/posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in   
    self.notifyNewPost()           
})
```

My question is, which (if one) function should I put this inside of the app delegate to have this run in the background? Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the answer you want to hear but Apple suspends...everything...in the background now. This looks like Firebase so your best bet is to learn javascript and make Firebase cloud functions to send push notifications

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the app delegate functions?

Comment: Those functions are usually just to do some cleaning up before it gets suspended. You used to be able to make a Data Service Class to keep listener objects active in the background but it doesn't work anymore either.

Comment: Then how do people get notifications from Instagram and messages even while they're not using the app?

Comment: The notifications are coming from Instagram itself not from the native code

Comment: Ok...I also have this method in the view controller (main feed page). Even if the user isn't in the app, would that still notify the user when there is a new post?

Comment: eventually the OS is going to turn off the Firebase listener object to save battery and memory. I could be wrong but I faced this exact problem before and the only solution I found was to use Firebase cloud functions.